# using the php 5.4's new constant ENT_DISALLOWED in htmlentities

Tags: php, utf-8, php-5.3, porting, html-entities

There is a string I'm trying to output in an htmlencoded way, and the [`htmlentities()` function](http://php.net/htmlentities) always returns an empty string.

I know exactly why it does so. Well, I am not running PHP 5.4 I got the latest PHP 5.3 flavor installed.

The question is how I am gonna be able to htmlencode a string which has invalid code unit sequences.

According to the manual, `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` is the way to go. But this constant is not defined in PHP 5.3.X.

I did this:

```
if (!defined('ENT_SUBSTITUTE')) {
    define('ENT_SUBSTITUTE', 8);
}
```

still no luck. `htmlentities` is still returning empty string.

I wanted to try `ENT_DISALLOWED` instead, but I cannot find its corresponding long value for it.

So my question is two folded

1. What's the constant value of PHP 5.4's `ENT_DISALLOWED`?
2. How do I make sure that a string containing non UTF-8 characters (such as the [*smart quotes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs)), can be cleared out of them? - Not just the smart quotes but anything that causes `htmlentities()` to return blank string.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that `htmlentities()` in PHP 5.3 does not have the `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` flag, however it has the (not really suggested) `ENT_IGNORE` flag. Be ware of the note and try to understand it before use:

> Using this flag is discouraged as it [» may have security implications](http://unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Deletion_of_Noncharacters).

It is far better that you understand why there is a problem with the input string in the first place. Most often users are only missing to specify the correct encoding.

E.g. first re-encode the string into UTF-8, then pass it to `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()`. Speaking of smart-quotes you are probably using a Windows-1252 encoded string. You won't even need to convert that one before use, you can just specify the charset properly (PHP 5.3):

```
htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, $encoding = 'Windows-1252');
```

Naturally this only works *if* the input *`$string`* is encoded in Windows-1252 (CP1252). Find out the correct encoding first, then it's normally no problem. For non-supported encodings re-encode into a supported one first, for example with [*iconv*](http://php.net/book.iconv) or [*mb_string*](http://php.net/book.mbstring).

Comment: If anyone happens to be looking for this because they are following Lynda.com MYSQL Essential Training and ran into "Use of undefined constant ENT_SUBSTITUTE" error on line 600 in Sid.php, I will tell you based on what I read here and that I could not find a clear equivalent flag for PHP 5.3, I went ahead and deleted that flag and the app works fine now. There are security implications as @hakre noted, but I'm working on a local development server with no access to the web.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, these constants [were added](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.strings.php) in `5.4.0`. The thing is, the support is new to `5.4.0` as well. Meaning you can pass whatever values you want, older `htmlentities` will not understand it.

As it is most probably the case, php changelog is quite misleading.